# "failed to compute cache key: failed to get state for index" error on earthly build on persistent CI node

Tags: earthly

My CI executes the following steps in sequence:

- `earthly +compile` (first make the code compiles)
- `earthly --push +package-and-containerize-all` (package to containers and push to registry)

The Earthfile code for targets looks like this:

```
resolve-gradle-dependencies: # <-- this step is to download dependencies only and reuse the result unless build configuration gets changed
    COPY gradle gradle
    COPY gradlew* .
    RUN ./gradlew --version
    COPY +collect-gradle-context/gradle_context .
    RUN ./gradlew

compile:
    FROM +resolve-gradle-dependencies
    COPY . . # <-- there is an appropriate .earthlyignore
    RUN ./gradlew classes


package-jar:
    FROM +compile
    RUN ./gradlew bootJar
    SAVE ARTIFACT build/libs/application.jar application.jar AS LOCAL build/libs/application.jar
    SAVE ARTIFACT build/libs/application.jar application.jar

extract-jar:
    COPY +package-jar/application.jar .
    RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract
    SAVE ARTIFACT . extracted-app

containerize-the-app:
    FROM jvm-runtime-distroless
    WORKDIR /opt/app
    COPY +extract-jar/extracted-app/dependencies/ ./
    COPY +extract-jar/extracted-app/spring-boot-loader/ ./
    COPY +extract-jar/extracted-app/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
    COPY +extract-jar/extracted-app/application/ ./
    ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
    SAVE IMAGE --push my-registry/my-service:latest

package-and-containerize-all:
    BUILD +containerize-the-app
    BUILD +containerize-e2e-tests # the code for this is omitted, because it's not involve in the error
```

Here is the `.earthlyignore`:

```
.git
.gitignore

.gradle/
**/build/
README.md

Earthfile
.earthlyignore
```

Getting this weird error on CI node after executing the pipeline several times:

```
            +compile | *cached* --> COPY . .
            +compile | *cached* --> RUN ./gradlew classes
        +package-jar | *cached* --> RUN ./gradlew bootJar
+package-e2e-tests-jar | WARN: Canceled
                 1/4 | WARN: Canceled
        +package-jar | WARN: Canceled
Share your logs with an Earthly account (experimental)! Register for one at https://ci.earthly.dev.
Error: build target: build main: failed to solve: async force execution for +extract-jar: unlazy force execution: failed to compute cache key: failed to get state for index 1 on [eyJpdHJubCI6dHJ1ZX0=] (fakecopy2) +extract-jar depends on +package-jar
```

I never face this error locally while developing the pipeline (I am using Mac + Docker for Mac), but it gets reproduced very quickly on CI node (which is a custom node, preserving it's state between runs to benefit from caching earthly targets). It takes 2-3 runs to reproduce the problem without source code change.

From the log above you can see that `extract-jar` has failed (which was invoked transitively for `+package-and-containerize-all`)

After that I am only able to bring my pipeline back to life on that particular CI node by inserting `earthly prune --all --reset` step in the very beginning of the pipeline.
To me the error message (`failed to compute cache key: failed to get state for index`) does not look very descriptive. What can cause the problem? I've also tried to a apply `--verbose` flag, but it did not give me more details on the error.